# Python BASE64SHA256 hash decodes different in comparison to .NET example

Tags: python, base64, sha256

I am trying to reproduce a procedure for creating unique transactions identifyiers (UTI), which are used for energy trading. According to the guidlines for good practice [text](https://remitcloud.de/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/ACER_REMIT_TRUM_ANNEX_IV_v2.1.docx), the UTI are generated according to three steps:

1. Transform the text to be hashed in a buffer of byte.
2. Apply the sha256 function (the sha256 function produces a buffer of 256 bits, normally every 8bits corresponds to 1 ASCII character, but if HEXADECIMAL code is used, 4 bits corresponds to a character).
3. Encode the result in BASE64 (in BASE64 every 6bit corresponds to a character so using 256/6 will result in 42 characters, with the remaining three characters being used to manage duplications).
   (The APIs used are the ones provided by .NET framework.)

An example is provided - several input values are concatenated to a string:
C0643778W.EUC06AG978W.EUFWELP2014-11-210.00223EUR1.0000000000MW10YCB-EUROPEU--82015-01-012015-01-31

After perfoming steps 1-3 the result is supposed to be the following:

> YwBycOVBTzf2d1nWsAF3CSNz1nbeF4TBNOKz0tHM26wC

In Python, I try to solve the problem with:

```
from base64 import b64encode
from hashlib import sha256

cs = "C0643778W.EUC06AG978W.EUFWELP2014-11-210.00223EUR1.0000000000MW10YCB-EUROPEU--82015-01-012015-01-31"
cs = cs.encode('ascii')
hs = hashlib.sha256()
hs.update(cs)
h64 = base64.b64encode(hs.digest()).decode("ascii")
```

The result is:

> Yw/ycOV/Tzf2d1nWsAF3CSNz1nbeF4TBNOKz0tHM26w=

Both strings are similar, but different regarding some characters.
I suggest that decoding of the base64 encoded string is performed differnt in python and the .NET environment.
Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Your .NET produced Base64 encoded string, decodes into 33 bytes, while SHA256 hashes are 32 bytes. Something doesn't add up on the .NET side.

Comment: [C# produces the same string as Python](https://ideone.com/yFWzC7)

Answer (score 1):

The base64 encoded string as calculated above is correct. However, the UTI-calculation algorithm used by ACER replaces special characters within the string after decoding.

- `+` to `A`
- `/` to `B`
- `=` to `C`
- `-` to `D`